# I am using SELECT2 drop down and adding images along with dropdown text in wordpress, but its not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-select2

The problem is I want to add select 2 dropdown in wordpress in my plugin file and with each text, image should be displayed.I have added script files using proper format but getting error.
this is the function in plugin file:

```
function wp_enqueue_scripts_callback(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css', array(), '4.1.0-rc.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js', 'jquery', '4.1.0-rc.0');
    //Add a JavaScript file to initialize the Select2 elements
    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2-init', '/wp-content/plugins/hblpay-gateway/select2-init.js', 'jquery');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_scripts_callback' );
```

and this is select2-init.js jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#social").select2({
        templateResult: formatState
    });
});

function formatState (state) {
    if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
    var $state = $('<span ><img sytle="display: inline-block;" src="images/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" /> ' + state.text + '</span>');
    return $state;
}
```

this is html :

```
<select id='social' style='width: 200px;'>
    <option value='facebook'>Facebook</option>
    <option value='twitter'>Twitter</option>
    <option value='linkedin'>Linkedin</option>
    <option value='google_plus'>Google Plus</option>
    <option value='vimeo'>Vimeo</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: _**but getting error.**_ Which error?

Comment: select 2 is not adding and no image is displayed due to wordpress may be.

Comment: in jquery file select2-init.js this function is not being called
templateResult: formatState

Comment: any one please answer?

Comment: when i refresh the page image is displayed in dropdown when the page finish loading it disappears

Comment: Have you an online preview?